# UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found

Tags: jwt, express-jwt

In our backend `routes/index.js`, we have

```
var auth = jwt({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, userProperty: 'payload' });

... ...

router.get('/ask', auth, function (req, res, next) {

    ... ...
}
```

I tried to test the `/ask` api from the frontend to backend in localhost. Here is a part of the code in the frontend:

```
async handleButtonClicked() {
    cost data: any = {}
    const token = await getSignToken();
    console.log(token);
    const headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token };
    await axios.get("https://localhost:3000/ask", data, { headers, withCredentials: true });
}
```

I then signed in the frontend webpage in localhost, then launched the above function. I did see the token printed in the console of dev tools of the frontend. And in the console of the backend, it showed that the api was called. But it raised an error `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found`.

Could anyone tell me what might be the reason? How could I debug?

Additionally, I have a doubt about the value of `process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY`. I see somewhere in our code it is just `JWT_SECRET_KEY`, somewhere in the production its a encrypted complex string. I would like to know if this secret is important (or maybe the reason of `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found`?). Should we always have the same secret in localhost and production?

PS: I cannot find `Authorization` in the headers of the `/ask` request from the frontend.

[image]

Comment: If you have frontend and backend in different origins, you will need to set cross origin cookies.

Comment: @AnishSapkota could you be more specific?

Comment: What are your frontend and backend origins?

Comment: frontend: `localhost:8000` and backend: `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await axios.get("https://localhost:3000/ask", data, { headers, withCredentials: true });`

should be

`await axios.post("https://localhost:3000/ask", data, { headers, withCredentials: true });`